# HSQLDB setting wrong input parameter name for procedure when preparing callablestatement

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc, hsqldb

This one is driving me crazy.

I am using HSQLDB as in memory database in one of my junit tests for a generic set of classes that I wrote for calling stored procedures.

**Initializing the db:**

```
@BeforeClass
public static void initializeDB() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    dataSource = new JDBCDataSource();
    dataSource.setDatabase("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb;shutdown=true");
    dataSource.setLoginTimeout(10);
    dataSource.setUser("sa");

    Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    statement.execute("CREATE TABLE users (id INTEGER, name VARCHAR(25), PRIMARY KEY(id))");
    statement.close();
    statement = connection.createStatement();
    statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO users VALUES(1, 'Ramiro')");
    statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO users VALUES(2, 'Chanukya')");
    statement.close();

    String storedProcedure1 = "CREATE PROCEDURE sp_say_hi(IN greeting_p VARCHAR(10)) "
            + "READS SQL DATA DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 2 "
            + "BEGIN ATOMIC "
            + "DECLARE result CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR SELECT COALESCE(greeting_p, 'Hi')+' '+name as greeting FROM users FOR READ ONLY; "
            + "DECLARE result1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR SELECT * FROM users FOR READ ONLY; "
            + "OPEN result; "
            + "OPEN result1; "
            + "END";

    statement = connection.createStatement();
    statement.execute(storedProcedure1);
    statement.close();

    connection.commit();
}
```

Then at some point inside the class that prepares the statement I use setObject method to register the input parameter:

```
...
CallableStatement callableStatement = con.prepareCall("{call sp_say_hi(?)}");
callableStatement.setObject("greeting_p", "Hola");
...
```

The setObject method throws a JavaSqlException with cause:

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Column not found: greeting_p
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
```

By using the debugger, I was able to find that there is a package private method in **org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCCallableStatement** class which is HSQLDB's implementation of CallableStatement, the method name is findParameterIndex which is called inside the setObject method, which checks if the provided parameter exists in the map of parameters from the procedure:

```
int findParameterIndex(String parameterName) throws SQLException {

    if (isClosed || connection.isClosed) {
        checkClosed();
    }

    int index = parameterNameMap.get(parameterName, -1);

    if (index >= 0) {
        return index + 1;
    }

    throw JDBCUtil.sqlException(ErrorCode.JDBC_COLUMN_NOT_FOUND,
                            parameterName);
}
```

by exploring that map using the debugger I was able to see that the parameter name is wrongly set by hsqldb, at least in this map:

```
[@p1, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

I was able to verify by changing the name in the setObject method call:

```
    callableStatement.setObject("@p1", "Hola");
```

After that it worked fine.

The weird thing is that if I retrieve the metadata of that procedure using DatabaseMetaData.getProcedureColumns method, the name of the param is correct from the jdbc metadata perspective:

```
DatabaseMetaData dbMetadata = con.getMetaData();
    ResultSet rs = dbMetadata.getProcedureColumns(con.getCatalog(),
            con.getSchema(),
            "SP_SAY_HI",
            "%_P");
        while(rs.next()) {
          // get stored procedure metadata
          String procedureCatalog     = rs.getString(1);
          String procedureSchema      = rs.getString(2);
          String procedureName        = rs.getString(3);
          String columnName           = rs.getString(4);
          short  columnReturn         = rs.getShort(5);
          int    columnDataType       = rs.getInt(6);
          String columnReturnTypeName = rs.getString(7);
          int    columnPrecision      = rs.getInt(8);
          int    columnByteLength     = rs.getInt(9);
          short  columnScale          = rs.getShort(10);
          short  columnRadix          = rs.getShort(11);
          short  columnNullable       = rs.getShort(12);
          String columnRemarks        = rs.getString(13);

          System.out.println("stored Procedure name="+procedureName);
          System.out.println("procedureCatalog=" + procedureCatalog);
          System.out.println("procedureSchema=" + procedureSchema);
          System.out.println("procedureName=" + procedureName);
          System.out.println("columnName=" + columnName);
          System.out.println("columnReturn=" + columnReturn);
          System.out.println("columnDataType=" + columnDataType);
          System.out.println("columnReturnTypeName=" + columnReturnTypeName);
          System.out.println("columnPrecision=" + columnPrecision);
          System.out.println("columnByteLength=" + columnByteLength);
          System.out.println("columnScale=" + columnScale);
          System.out.println("columnRadix=" + columnRadix);
          System.out.println("columnNullable=" + columnNullable);
          System.out.println("columnRemarks=" + columnRemarks);
        }
```

It prints out:

```
stored Procedure name=SP_SAY_HI
procedureCatalog=PUBLIC
procedureSchema=PUBLIC
procedureName=SP_SAY_HI
columnName=GREETING_P
columnReturn=1
columnDataType=12
columnReturnTypeName=CHARACTER VARYING
columnPrecision=10
columnByteLength=0
columnScale=0
columnRadix=0
columnNullable=1
columnRemarks=null
```

Note that the name is coming in upper case, I already check that. I changed the registering of the parameter name to upper case in the setObject method to see if that helped, but didn't make a difference.

**Update:**
I created a ticket in HSQLDB issue tracking system, they just fixed it and committed to current realease: https://sourceforge.net/p/hsqldb/bugs/1431/

Comment: Thanks for your latest update. Please consider adding your own answer to this question indicating that the issue will be fixed in the next version of HSQLDB.

Answer (score 3):

I created a ticket in HSQLDB issue tracking system, they just fixed it and committed to next release, for more info: https://sourceforge.net/p/hsqldb/bugs/1431/

Answer (score 2):

I think it is safest to always use the *parameter index* when you bind the variable to the stored procedure call, using the `setX()` methods inherited from [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), e.g.:

```
callableStatement.setString(1, "Hola");
```

From the JavaDocs of [`Connection.prepareCall()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareCall%28java.lang.String%29):

> Some drivers may send the call statement to the database when the method prepareCall is done; others may wait until the CallableStatement object is executed.

If the driver doesn't communicate with the DB before `execute()` is called, then there is no way for it to know the names of the parameters, either, because the bind variables in JDBC queries are always anonymous. It seems that the HSQLDB driver is indeed unaware of the actual parameter names when the binding happens as it uses placeholder names (`@p1` etc.) internally.

Comment: What you say makes sense as it would explain why some frameworks like Spring JdbcTemplate, specifically talking about SimpleJdbcCall and its helper classes use position based approach when setting parameters, what they do as I see from their code is to first retrieve the position of the param using db metadata using for example the getProcedureColumns method and then using that position in a setX method.

Comment: However is still interesting how the driver knows about the existence of the '@p1' parameter if it has not communicated with the DB at that stage.

Comment: How does the SQL used for the procedure call look like, in variable `sqlCall`? If it has bind placeholders (question marks), then the driver knows how many parameters to expect.

Comment: @raspacorp - I agree with Mick's assessment. I don't think this is a matter of you *or* HSQLDB doing anything "incorrectly", it may simply be that HSQLDB does not support the use of parameter names when assigning values in `.set...` statements. The HSQLDB [documentation](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/sqlroutines-chapt.html#src_routine_definition) makes no mention of optional parameters, so if all parameters must be represented in the CALL then their values can simply be supplied by number (1..n) in the order defined by the PROCEDURE declaration.

Comment: @MickMnemonic sorry I didn't provide the value of sqlCall in the question, I just updated it: {call sp_say_hi(?)}